# AdobeAcrobatのアクションウィザードで文章の右綴じ設定を行う方法。

Tags: javascript

AdobeAcrobatのアクションウィザードで右綴じ設定を行う方法を探しています。

以下のリファレンスを見た限りでは、専用の関数やプロパティは用意されていないようです。
https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/jp/acrobat/kb/511/511727/attachments/511727_js_api_reference.pdf

調べたところ、メタデータのCatalog/ViewerPreference/DirectionにR2Lを設定すれば良いらしいですが、設定方法がわかりません。
上記リファレンスp245にメタデータ設定のサンプルがありますが

```
var meta = this.metadata;
var myXMPData = new XML(meta);
myXMPData.Calalog.ViewerPreferences.Direction = "R2L"
myNewXMPStr=myXMPData.toXMLString();
this.metadata = myNewXMPStr;
```

としても、エラーとなります。
そもそも、pdfのメタデータに関する知識が皆無なので、上記サンプルのnamespaceなども理解できていない状況です....
ご存じの方がいれば、ご教授頂きたいです。